# How to Keeps the checked Items On filtering ListGrid smartgwt

Tags: filtering, smartgwt, listgrid

I am using the smartgwt 4.0, I have a listgrid showing many personal items 
I want to implement Maintaining Check Box State of a personal item selected in listGrid while Search on the filter  any body know please help me.